# CFML / Fusebox: Several problems and errors with /parsed files

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016, fusebox

There is a live and a development environment of a Fusebox 5.5.1 application. Everything works fine in the last one. And also the live version worked normal until a week ago. There were no changes to the code in between. Then, the following error message appeared:

> Context validation error for the cfcatch tag.
>   The tag must be nested inside a CFTRY tag.
>   The error occured in:
>   C:/home/domain.com/wwwroot/live/parsed/example.view.cfm

I checked both parsed files and noted that the live version has generated a slightly different file, although the program code is identical.

I deleted all `/parsed` files and made a full update from dev to live. This did not work.

Fusebox generates the application name depending on the directory. When I changed the directory name from `/live` to `/livex`, it suddenly worked again. When I restored the original name, the error recurred.

The error might have been fixed because it was a "new" application due to the name change and possibly new or different server resources were deployed?

---

In addition, there is another problem:

> Unexpected attributes    Unexpected attributes were found in a
>   'xfa' verb in fuseaction person.$prefuseaction.

In this case, the / parsed file is not created at all. It's the same situation, live and dev are identical, dev works and live does not. I even removed all `xfa` variables and replaced them with `cfset` in the PreFuseAction area of the `circuit.xml` file. It still worked in /dev, but same error in /live.

The live version is now back in production mode and I copied all `/parsed` files from dev to live. That works for now for both errors, but only until the live application generates new `/parsed` files.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening there?

---

Here is some server information from CF Administrator

*System Information / Server Details*

- **Server Product**     ColdFusion 2016
- **Version**    2016.0.05.303689
- **Tomcat Version**     8.5.11.0
- **Edition**    Enterprise
- **Operating System**   Windows NT (unknown)
- **OS Version**     10.0
- **Update Level**   C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/lib/updates/chf20160005.jar
- **Adobe Driver Version**   5.1.4 (Build 0001)

Comment: Clear the template cache.

Comment: Did not fix the problem. First i deleted 2 parsed files in /live and /dev, one for each error message. Then i deleted the template cache of the /live and /dev directory and reloaded the page. The error messages occurred again in /live, /dev works. Since this had no effect, I deleted the entire template cache. But even this had no effect. Then i copied the new parsed files again from /dev to /live.

Comment: Can you add the `circuit.xml` to the question?